# Generics and inheritance in Java library used from Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, inheritance

I'm having problem implementing a Kotlin class which uses Java-defined generics/interfaces classes from MockMvc library.

Library classes:

```
public interface ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<B extends ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<B>> extends MockMvcBuilder {

    // ...

    <T extends B> T defaultRequest(RequestBuilder requestBuilder);

    // ...

}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface MockMvcBuilderCustomizer {

    /**
     * Customize the given {@code builder}.
     * @param builder the builder
     */
    void customize(ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<?> builder);

}
```

I would like to implement this (in Java) :

```
@Component
public class ApiKeyHeaderMockMvcBuilderCustomizer implements MockMvcBuilderCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<?> builder) {
        RequestBuilder apiKeyRequestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("any")
            .header("api-key-header", "apikeyvalue");
        builder.defaultRequest(apiKeyRequestBuilder);
    }    
}
```

But when I try to rewrite the above class in Kotlin, I'm having troubles figuring out what generic constraint I should use both in `customize`'s parameter and when calling `builder.defaultRequest`

```
@Component
class ApiKeyHeaderMockMvcBuilderCustomizer : MockMvcBuilderCustomizer {
    // is this generic right?
    override fun customize(builder: ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<*>) { 
        val apiKeyRequestBuilder: RequestBuilder =
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://any")
                .header("api-key-header", "apikeyvalue")

        // won't compile, using Nothing compiles but fails at runtime
        builder.defaultRequest<*>(apiKeyRequestBuilder)
    }
}
```

Copy-pasting the code from Java in IntelliJ Idea converts to this Kotlin code :

```
@Component
class ApiKeyHeaderMockMvcBuilderCustomizer : MockMvcBuilderCustomizer {
    override fun customize(builder: ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<*>) {
        val apiKeyRequestBuilder: RequestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("any")
            .header("api-key-header", "apikeyvalue")
        builder.defaultRequest(apiKeyRequestBuilder)
    }
}
```

With error under `defaultRequest` :

```
Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in 
fun <T : Nothing!> defaultRequest(requestBuilder: RequestBuilder) : T
Please specify it explicitly.
```

When I try using `Nothing` or `Nothing?` in as generic parameter for `defaultRequest`, I get runtime `NullPointerException` in place of the method call. The implementation of the defaultRequest method is :

```
public abstract class AbstractMockMvcBuilder<B extends AbstractMockMvcBuilder<B>>
        extends MockMvcBuilderSupport implements ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<B> {

    @Override
    public final <T extends B> T defaultRequest(RequestBuilder requestBuilder) {
        this.defaultRequestBuilder = requestBuilder;
        return self();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <T extends B> T self() {
        return (T) this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to copy the Java class and paste it to a Kotlin project in IntelliJ? It should convert it to Kotlin.

Comment: @JakubZalas Tried that, see my edit.

Comment: does this help? https://typealias.com/guides/star-projections-and-how-they-work/

Comment: "using Nothing compiles but fails at runtime" - what error message do you get?

Comment: @k314159 See my edit.

Comment: @Stachu I've read it. But I'm having hard time with the compiler. My understanding is that the generic parameter for defaultRequest should be Any, as it returns generic typed value. But compiler expects it to be Nothing and when I use Any, compiler complains.

Comment: and what happends when you replace both `<*>` with `<Any>` in ApiKeyHeaderMockMvcBuilderCustomizer?

Comment: @Stachu When I use `ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<Any>` then it doesn't see the `customize` method as valid override. "Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature `public abstract fun customize(builder: ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<*>!): Unit` and `public open fun customize(builder: ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<Any>): Unit`"

Comment: I'm now thinking about different Null handling between Java and Kotlin. What happens when you use`customize(builder: ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<*>?) ` and `builder?.defaultRequest<Nothing>(apiKeyRequestBuilder)`?

Comment: @Stachu Nope, still the same.

Comment: how about `ApiKeyHeaderMockMvcBuilderCustomizer<T :Nothing?>` and `builder.defaultRequest<T>(apiKeyRequestBuilder)`?

Comment: @Stachu That is not even valid syntax. It is looking for T as existing type, not a generic type name.

Comment: it looks valid in my IDE same as this `interface Test<T:Nothing?>{fun a(t:T)}`

Comment: @Stachu That is  class/interface syntax, not function syntax.

Comment: that's why I added `ApiKeyHeaderMockMvcBuilderCustomizer<T :Nothing?>`. As per your original error message it expliciltly specifies the T for defaultRequest

Comment: @Stachu Sorry, I didn't understand what you said there. And yes, that seems to have solved the problem. Using `ApiKeyHeaderMockMvcBuilderCustomizer<T : Nothing?>` will compile and won't throw `NullReferenceException`. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If you are getting an NPE when using `Nothing`, is that because `defaultRequest` is returning `null`? Maybe Kotlin's stricter type-checking is showing you a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the compiler asks for the explicit type:

```kotlin
Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in 
fun <T : Nothing!> defaultRequest(requestBuilder: RequestBuilder) : T
Please specify it explicitly.
```

you can specify it like this:

```kotlin
@Component
class ApiKeyHeaderMockMvcBuilderCustomizer<T :Nothing?> : MockMvcBuilderCustomizer {
    override fun customize(builder: ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<*>) {
        val apiKeyRequestBuilder: RequestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("any")
            .header("api-key-header", "apikeyvalue")
        builder.defaultRequest<T>(apiKeyRequestBuilder)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works. Would you be able to clarify on why this works and why just Nothing doesn't?

Comment: Does `defaultRequest<Nothing?>` work too, without declaring the `T` parameter? If it works, can't see how `defaultRequest` could be returning anything other than `null`, because it's impossible to return `Nothing`.