# How to conform Java upper bounded wildcard type parameter to Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

Given

```
public interface StubTransformer {
    AbstractStub<?> transform(String name, AbstractStub<?> stub);
}
```

and

```
public static <T extends AbstractStub<T>> T attachHeaders(T stub, Metadata extraHeaders) {...}
```

this Kotlin class fails to compile.

```
class MetadataInjectingStubTransformer: StubTransformer {
    override fun transform(name: String, stub: AbstractStub<*>): AbstractStub<*> {
        val header = Metadata()
        return MetadataUtils.attachHeaders(stub, header)
    }
}
```

Error

```
Type parameter bound for T in 

fun <T : AbstractStub<T!>!> attachHeaders(stub: T!, extraHeaders: Metadata!): T!
is not satisfied: inferred type AbstractStub<*>! is not a subtype of AbstractStub<AbstractStub<*>!>!
```

but the Java version can be forced to compile.

```
public class MetadataInjectingStubTransformer implements StubTransformer {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractStub<?> transform(String name, AbstractStub stub) {
        Metadata header = new Metadata();    
        return MetadataUtils.attachHeaders(stub, header);
    }
}
```

How do we make the Kotlin code compile?

Comment: What's inside `AbstractStub`?

Comment: @AnggrayudiH Not sure what you mean by “inside”, but [here](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/AbstractStub.html) is the Javadoc, you can see for yourself. Not that it matters anyway because the problem isn’t with `AbstractStub`.

Comment: Related: [Generics and inheritance in Java library used from Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807526/generics-and-inheritance-in-java-library-used-from-kotlin)

Comment: Both your question and the linked question are about confirming to Java wildcard types in Kotlin. They are related. It's useful to point out related questions. It's not useful to make tangential comments about Thai yellow curry and what's wrong with this site. I don't know the answer, hence why I didn't answer, but I would like to know the answer and think it's a good question, hence why I upvoted, and think it's related to the other question, hence why I posted the link.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Yes, but as you noted yourself, the accepted answer in the other question uses `Nothing`, which can't return anything. That's not the case here. The other question is actually special case of my question, not the other way around. I also see a close vote, which I assume generated from your comment (since you indicated they are similar questions).